# What is this bush/tree and can it be heavily pruned?

Tags: identification, pruning, transplanting

I have this growing in our back yard here in the Pacific North West US:

[image]

(Photo taken in late March)

It's full of these drooping white flowers and (what I think are) new red leaves. Feels kind of tropical.

Right now it's about 10' tall. I'm not sure if it's a bush or a tree (or if it matters).

The problem is that it was planted about 6' away from a nice Japanese Maple. So this looks rather silly at this scale next to the diminutive maple.

My question(s):

- does anyone know what this is?
- at this size, could it be heavily pruned to encourage new growth and then maintained at a more manageable size (say 4' or so)
- at this size, could it be dug up and replanted somewhere else?
- if it can be heavily pruned, can that be done now, or should I wait until next winter to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [*Pieris japonica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pieris_japonica) of some variety, and these do make between 10 and 12 feet. They don't like being heavily pruned on a regular basis, so keeping it small isn't an option, and at that height, this is a mature shrub which, if it's to survive, would need a crane and a tarpaulin to lift out the (massive) rootball. If the Acer's (Japanese maple) not been in long, move that elsewhere instead.

Comment: That looks like it! Well, I'm not about to get a crane, so it looks like I'll risk the pruning. Worse case, we just have to get rid of it and plant a new one some where else.